# Changes made to Navigation Controller are not shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I copied the example from View Controller Catalog for iOS made some changes to the colour and expected to see them reflected on the simulator. Nothing happens ???

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Override point for customization after application launch.

UIViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

navigationController.title = @"Hello";

navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack ;

navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

window.rootViewController = navigationController;

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES; }
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: nothing happens? pls explain

Answer (score 0):

Several things: First: be sure than in the General information of your target app, in Main Interface field is blank. (If you don´t find it, delete all *.storyboard files that you have).

Second: In your AppDelegate.h should be this property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

And last: Change this in your code:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In order to know changes is better step by step. (.title is in ViewController).

Comment: Onik, I implemented your suggestions and it works now. Many Thanks, David